# how to read such XML format "<loca:user>" in php and convert to array or object

Tags: php, xml

How to read such XML format in PHP

```
<Data xmlns:loc="loc">
                <loc:user>
                    <loc:userID>12861320</loc:userID>
                    <loc:userMSISDN>244642867</loc:userMSISDN>
                    <loc:userExpiryDate>2019-06-30 17:09:05</loc:userExpiryDate>
                    <loc:userStatus>QUEUE</loc:userStatus>
                </loc:user>             </Data>
```

I am using SimpleXMLElement but it is not able to read those data

Comment: Using [`simplexml_load_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).

Comment: I am using SimpleXMLElement but it is not able to read those data

Comment: That is an XML with namespaces. The actual value of the `xmlns:loc` is the namespace.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
$xml = '<Data xmlns:loc="loc">
            <loc:user>
                <loc:userID>12861320</loc:userID>
                <loc:userMSISDN>244642867</loc:userMSISDN>
                <loc:userExpiryDate>2019-06-30 17:09:05</loc:userExpiryDate>
                <loc:userStatus>QUEUE</loc:userStatus>
            </loc:user>             
        </Data>';


$xml= preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $xml); // adding this worked for me
$array = json_decode(json_encode((array)simplexml_load_string($xml)),true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [locuser] => Array
        (
            [locuserID] => 12861320
            [locuserMSISDN] => 244642867
            [locuserExpiryDate] => 2019-06-30 17:09:05
            [locuserStatus] => QUEUE
        )

)
```

Comment: SimpleXML and DOM can parse XML with namespaces just fine, here is no need to use string functions and remove that information.